# Getting information about issues in the SonarQube 5.0 API

Tags: sonarqube

I would like some suggestions about the best way to go about interrogating the SonarQube 5.0 API. I am trying to find out the number of issues that are flagged in each of all the services that exist but am trouble finding a way to go about formulating a call for that on this version of Sonar, even in the documents.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That version is not supported anymore. The latest LTS version is 6.7.6; you should upgrade your instance.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Oh I agree in that regard but unfortunately that's currently not an option :(